# Show that $x^7 + 5x^5 + 2x - 2$ has an inverse $g(x)$ and compute $g'(-2)$.

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

It's easy to prove it has an inverse however I'm unable to calculate the inverse and thus its derivate and I'm not sure how to use the inverse function rule in this case. Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: strictly monotone functions have inverses.

Comment: I have tried to equate the function to -2 so that I could use f'(x) = 1/(g'(f(x)) [inverse rule] however I am unable to calculate beyond x^7 + 5x^5 + 2x = 0.

Comment: Inverse functions are reflection of curve along line y=x, So replacing x and y in the original equation will give you Implicit equation of the inverse function

Comment: I'm aware of the method of swapping y and x however due to the degree of the function I don't know how it would be solved. Can you please solve?

Comment: @AdityaShahi, By solving it, do you mean finding y in terms of x explicitly, If so , Why do you need to do that? Question mentioned above don't ask you to do that, You can even work with implicit functions to find derivatives

Comment: " I am unable to calculate beyond x^7 + 5x^5 + 2x = 0": can't you see an obvious root of this equation? [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^7+5x^5+2x-2$$
$$f^{-1}(-2)=a$$
$$f(a)=-2$$
$$a=0$$
$$(f^{-1}(-2))'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(-2))}=\frac{1}{f'(0)}$$

Comment: Thank you Mr. Emil! :)

Comment: You're welcome.